# What is this component from a SCADA?

Tags: identification, hmi

I decided to join here as I can't find this specific component on the web and I might as well ask here.

So I have a broken HMI/Scada screen and on the motherboard I found a burnt component, but I don't recognize it and don't find any info when I search for the text written on it.

`R33 821 R5S`

See pictures:

[image: Burnt]
<sub>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJU2Q.jpg</sub>

[image: Not burnt]
<sub>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDx8m.jpg</sub>

Comment: It's a 330nH shielded inductor of some kind. Finding the exact part will be hard. It's also unlikely to be the root cause of your problem.

Comment: If it uses a Celeron CPU, chances are the CPU is shorted.  Likely time to find another unit and make one good one out of both.

Answer (score 3):

The part in question is an inductor. It's likely that the `R33` on the first line means 0.33 μH, or 330 nH. (R is commonly used in place of a decimal point in markings like this, because it's harder to miss a big `R` than a small `.`. Why R specifically is beyond the scope of this answer.)

Judging by the package, it appears to be a shielded inductor--possibly a molded type.

Note, however, that the damaged one has different markings. It's hard to read, but I believe it says `2R2`, which would imply 2.2 μH.

Current ratings and such are impossible to tell; you'd have to find the exact part number to get a datasheet for that.

However, I think it's unlikely that this inductor is your problem. Inductors very rarely fail--it's likely that this one only failed because something else failed first, causing excessive current through the inductor. If you don't replace that something else, any replacement inductor will end up just as dead as this one.